# Netsuite doesn't maintain the file extension

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

The problem is that when I uploaded the file in netsuite's file cabinet by giving the name to the file,netsuite saves that file as 'Other Binary file' and don't maintain file's actual extension. Why it so ? 
Like this Url:
/core/media/media.nl?id=3219&c=3960047&h=9e04f9ffc7999b60d6c2&_xt=.bin

If I uploaded a file by not giving the name then everything is fine.

I am doing a customization in which I need to know the file extension but if the user uploaded a file by giving the name to it I am not able retrieve the file extension.

Comment: What type of file are you uploading?  I have seen this (known issue) with certain Microsoft files.  The files are stored properly, but NetSuite does not know what program they are supposed to be associated with.

Answer (score 0):

If this is dealing with the Microsoft files, here is the NetSuite answer for correcting this.  Just FYI.  I found this by searching the SuiteAnswers site for "Other Binary File."

[Microsoft Office 2007 File Appears as Other Binary File Type When Attached to a Record in NetSuite](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14495)

Comment: It was misunderstanding on my part. The problem is not while uploading but when I use nlapiSubmitFile(file). In my code I load the file, make it 'available online' by file.setIsOnline(true) and submit it. After submit the file the extension of the file become .bin

Comment: You should just need to set the full filename when you are creating the file, then.

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work. The problem occurs when file name doesn't contain file extension. If say filename is 'my pic' although its .jpg file but if submit the file with nlapiSubmitFile() then netsuite change the extension to .bin. I think its bug in nlapiSubmitFile() function. If filename contains extension like 'mypic.jpg' then everything is fine.

Comment: That would be built in functionality.  The only solution would be to check the file type in your code and add it to the filename when you upload.